# System.IO Performance Issues over Network

Tags: c#, filereader, .net

I am iterating a large directory(500 GB) over a Network, i need to iterate all the files from root and inside sub directories,here is my sample code

```
    static void WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo root, DbContext dbcontext)
    {
                FileInfo[] files = null;
                DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Listing files...");
                    files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Files obtained.");
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                {

                }

                catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Debug.Print(e.Message);
                }

                if (files != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Iterating files...");
                    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Indexing [" + fi.FullName + "]...");
                        doIndex(IndexData index = new IndexData();

                        index.attachementUID = fi.Name;
                        dbcontext.IndexDatas.Add(index);

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " File iteration completed.");
                    subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

                    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
                    {
                        WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo,dbcontext);
                    }
            }
  }
```

Performance is very slow, i am reading file name and file path, So can you guys recommend something, which i can use to iterate all the files from a Network path, how to improve current code, any System.IO improvements and alternatives.

Secondly how can i keep track of my position in file System. i iterate half way and application crashed, how can i start iterating again from same position?

Comment: Out of experience: Firectory SIZE - as in GB - is irrelevant. Directory ITEMS count is not. I.e. 1 file of 400gb is 1 file, 1 million files is a million more operations when iteracting over the DirectoryInfo.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()` rather than `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`, from MSDN:

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

Comment: I second that. But note that `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()` was new in .Net 4.

Comment: @EagleBeak Yeh I only *recently* discovered it as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution at the end - you can make the problem smaller, but not go away. Getting DirectoryInfo objects of a large number of files (file size is irrelevant) is a slow operation even locally, over the network it just takes time.

A 10g network can help a little, as do faster discs, but this just is not an operation that is optimized for high throughput.